# Trouble handling partitions

Tags: partitioning

When I installed Ubuntu, for some reason I encrypted the Hard Disk and uninstalled  my Windows. Now I am missing some programs that aren't available on Ubuntu and I would like to keep both OS's on my PC. My question is: How can I decrypt my hard disk and manage my partitions so I can reinstall my Windows 8?

```
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA ST9500325AS (scsi)

Disk /dev/sda: 500GB

Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B

Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags

 1     1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32              boot

 2     538MB   794MB  256MB   ext2

 3     794MB   500GB  499GB
```

I have no idea what these partitions means, I'm just a typical user that gave a shot to Ubuntu (definitely not disappointed) but now I'm having this issue. 
Thanks in advance and sorry for the ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- You can shrink your last partition roughly in half and install windows on the free space
- You can backup any data from your Linux system, install Windows from scratch, install Ubuntu in dual boot mode (I think it is called side-by-side in the installation wizard) and restore your Ubuntu data.

The second option would probably be a bit easier since you will not have to mess around with shrinking an encrypted partition.

Comment: I tried to follow the second option.

Comment: When I was installing Windows I formated every partition (apparently I wasn't suppose to do that), now I don't have ubuntu anymore and when I try to install Windows (downloaded via DreamSpark) it announces an error and restart the computer. Did I made some huge mistake, I`m already thinking about reinstall ubuntu and forget about Windows...